# pull docker image from private registry through maven settings.xml

Tags: spring-boot, maven, configuration-files, testcontainers

I'm setting up a custom TestContainer by pulling an image from a private registry. At the moment it looks like this (it works):

```
   public static GenericContainer<?> customContainer = new GenericContainer<>(
      DockerImageName.parse("private-registry.net:port/path/custom-image"))
      .withCreateContainerCmdModifier(cmd -> cmd.withName("Test_Custom").withHostName("custom"))
```

I'm setting the login information through `System.setProperty("registry.username", "username")` (same for password). I don't want my login to be plaintext code. The idea is to login through settings.xml where the private repositories are defined. I'm completely new to this so I don't know if that's even possible? I've tried just adding it into the xml file like so:

```
<repositories>
   <id>custom-image</id>
   <url>private-registry.net:port/path/custom-image</url>
   ......
</repositories>
<servers>
       <server>
            <id>custom-image</id>
            <username>username</username>
            <password>password</password>
        </server>
</servers>
```

It doesn't seem to "detect" automatically, how do I get the container to refer to its url and credentials within the xml? Or is this not possible? I only see answers on how you push an image through maven.

Comment: The access to a docker registry is not controlled by using something from settings.xml. This is part of Docker which means you need to configure the access via daemon.json and do also a docker login upfront.

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm logging in via setting the registry.name and registry.password, is that a daemon.json setting?

Comment: These look like your Maven registry settings to me. Testcontainers takes it from usual Docker credential locations (there are many available). After you do a `docker login`, it should work in your environment.